# React datepicker parsing selected date

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-datepicker

I have the following component:

```
import React, {Component, Fragment} from 'react';
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
// import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class Form extends Component {
    state = { 
        selected: new Date()
    }

    handleChange = date => {
        console.log('date: ', date)
        this.setState({
            selected: date
        });
    }

    render() { 
        const {selected} = this.state;
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <form>
                    <DatePicker
                        dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy" 
                        onChange={this.handleChange} 
                        selected={selected}
                    />
                    <button>search</button>
                </form>
            </Fragment>
        );
    }
}

export default Form;
```

when I select any date from the datepicker I get the following format:

*date:  Wed May 15 2019 12:54:33 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)*

can this be parsed back to a format like:

*`2019-05-15/yyyy-mm-dd`*

as I will need it to submit in that format for an API call?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yep, most easily by using an established library such as [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/).

Then you can parse the date into whatever format you like as such:

```
date = moment(date).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
```